# why static method can not be called inside instance method?

Tags: python

The error says that global name "get_words" is not defined. But I did define a static method named get_words. What should I do if I want to call get_words function inside train()

```
class classfier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fc = {}
        self.cc = {}

    @staticmethod
    def get_words(item):
        words = re.split(r"\W+",item.strip())
        words =  [element.lower() for element in words if len(element)>2 and len(element)<20]
        return set(words)

    def train(self,item,cat):
        features = get_words(item)
        for f in features:
            self.incf(f,cat)
        self.incc(cat)
```

Comment: `get_words(item)` should be `classifier.get_words(item)`.

Comment: You need to call `self.get_words` (or `classifier.get_words`).

Comment: @DeepSpace don't use the class name please, it's brittle at best. Just call `self.get_words(...)`, it's garanteed to be correctly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the fact they take neither the instance nor class as first argument, staticmethods are not different from instancemethods or classmethods: they are attributes of the class, and the same lookup rules apply as for any other attribute lookup. IOW: you have to look it up on either the class or an instance of it. Since you're calling from within an instancemethod, the obvious thing to do is an instance lookup, ie:

```
def train(self,item,cat):
    features = self.get_words(item)
```

With your original code (`features = get_words(...)`), Python will look first for a local name (local to the function's body), then for a global (module-level) name - and fail with a NameError if it doesn't find any. Remember that in Python everything is an object (including functions, classes and modules) so everything shares the same namespace and lookup rules.

Answer (score -1):

Calling a static method inside of an instance needs the name of the Class as identifier:

```
features = classfier.get_words(item)
```

will work. `self` always refers to the object or instance itself, a class or static method or value can be called by the class name.

Comment: Right, I changed my answer.

Comment: "Calling a static method inside of an instance needs the name of the Class as identifier:" => sorry but this is just plain wrong. You can call a staticmethod directly on the instance, and that's very obviously the right thing to do when calling it from within an instancemethod.

Comment: it _will_ work. Nothing magic here, it's just plain attribute lookup, following the very same rules as just any other attribute lookup in Python.

Answer (score -1):

in C++

```
class Something
{
private:
    static int s_value;
public:
    static int getValue() { return s_value; } // static member function
};

int Something::s_value = 1; // initializer

int main()
{
    std::cout << Something::getValue() << '\n';
}
```

In Java -

```
class Student9{  
 int rollno;  
 String name;  
 static String college = "ITS";  

 static void change(){  
 college = "BBDIT";  
 }  

 Student9(int r, String n){  
 rollno = r;  
 name = n;  
 }  

 void display (){System.out.println(rollno+" "+name+" "+college);}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
Student9.change();  

Student9 s1 = new Student9 (111,"Indian");  
Student9 s2 = new Student9 (222,"American");  
Student9 s3 = new Student9 (333,"China");  

s1.display();  
s2.display();  
s3.display();  
}
}
```

And finally in Python -

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def the_static_method(x):
        print x

MyClass.the_static_method(2) # outputs 2
```

See everywhere we use the class name to call the static method! and here is something for you from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

> Return a static method for function.
>
> A static method does not receive an implicit first argument. To
>   declare a static method, use this idiom:
>
> class C(object):
>       @staticmethod
>       def f(arg1, arg2, ...):
>           ... The @staticmethod form is a function decorator – see the description of function definitions in Function definitions for
>   details.
>
> It can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance
>   (such as C().f()). The instance is ignored except for its class.
>
> Static methods in Python are similar to those found in Java or C++.
>   Also see classmethod() for a variant that is useful for creating
>   alternate class constructors.
>
> For more information on static methods, consult the documentation on
>   the standard type hierarchy in The standard type hierarchy.
>
> New in version 2.2.
>
> Changed in version 2.4: Function decorator syntax added.

As mentioned in the comment, this is what you should be doing when you are calling a static method from outside a class instance method. However, if you want to call a static method from inside a class's instance method then using self is probably the best idea and let the interpreter resolve the reference for you. Sorry for the little confusion. I tried to provide the comparison among three languages and tried to explain things but kind of missed the main point a bit.

Comment: "See everywhere we use the class name to call the static method" => as mentionned in the doc Python lets you call a staticmethod directly from an instance, and that's the RightThing(tm) to do when calling it from an instance method.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I was wrong in the way I tried to express it. I have edited my answer. Thanks for the catch.